# Python 2.7 using if elif to go through a text file

Tags: python, if-statement

Goal is to write a script which will copy a text file and exclude any line beginning with #.

My question is I seem to get an index error which is dependent upon the order of my if elif conditions.  The only difference between the nonworking code and the working code (besides the suffix "_bad" to the nonworking function name) is that I test the "" condition first (works) vs testing the "#" condition first (doesn't work)

Base file is created by this script:

```
>>> testFileObj = open("test.dat","w")  
>>> testFileObj.write("#line one\nline one\n#line two\nline two\n")  
>>> testFileObj.close()
```

Code which works:

```
def copyAndWriteExcludingPoundSigns(origFile, origFileWithOutPounds):    
    origFileObj = open(origFile,"r")  
    modFileObj = open(origFileWithOutPounds,"w")  
    while True:  
        textObj = origFileObj.readline()    
        if textObj == "":    
            break    
        elif textObj[0] == "#":    
            continue    
        else:    
            modFileObj.write(textObj)    
    origFileObj.close()    
    modFileObj.close()
```

Code which doesn't work:

```
def copyAndWriteExcludingPoundSigns_Bad(origFile, origFileWithOutPounds):  
    origFileObj = open(origFile,"r")  
    modFileObj = open(origFileWithOutPounds,"w")  
    while True:  
        textObj = origFileObj.readline()  
        if textObj[0] == "#":  
            continue  
        elif textObj == "":  
            break  
        else:  
            modFileObj.write(textObj)  
    origFileObj.close()  
    modFileObj.close()
```

Which gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#96>", line 1, in <module>
    copyAndWriteExcludingPoundSigns_Bad("test.dat","testOutput.dat")
  File "<pyshell#94>", line 6, in copyAndWriteExcludingPoundSigns_Bad
    if textObj[0] == "#":
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Instead of `while True: textObj = origFileObj.readline()` use `for textObj in origFileObj.readline()`.

Comment: Indent the code would not be a bad idea

Answer (score 5):

If you do

```
if textObj[0] == "#":
```

and textObj="" then there is no character at the zero index, because the string is empty, hence the index error.

The alternative is to do

```
 if textObj.startswith("#"):
```

which will work in both cases.

Answer (score 5):

some tips (and please please read [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)):

- use a 'for' instead of a 'while' loop
- no need to use readlines after python 2.4
- test if the line is empty before testing for the first char

Untested:

```
def copy_and_write_excluding_pound_signs(original, filtered):
    original_file = open(original,"r")
    filtered_file = open(filtered,"w")
    for line in original_file:
        if line and line[0] == '#':
            continue
        filtered_file.write(line)
    original_file.close()
    filtered_file.close()
```

You may also want to filter a line with some white space befor the '#':

```
import re

def copy_and_write_excluding_pound_signs(original, filtered):
    pound_re = re.compile(r'^\s*#')
    original_file = open(original,"r")
    filtered_file = open(filtered,"w")
    for line in original_file:
        if pound_re.match(line):
            continue
        filtered_file.write(line)
    original_file.close()
    filtered_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `line.startswith('#')` to check whether the string `line` starts with `'#'`. If the line is empty (such as `line = ''`), there would be no first character, and you'd get this error.

Also the existence of a line that an empty string isn't guaranteed, so breaking out of the loop like that is inadvisable. Files in Python are iterable, so can simply do a `for line in file:` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your non-working code is that it is encountering an empty line, which is causing the IndexError when the statement `if textObj[0] == "#":` is evaluated (`[0]` is a reference to the first element of string). The working code avoids doing that when the line is empty.

The simpliest way I can think of to rewrite your function is to use `for line in <fileobj>` you won't have worry about `line` ever being empty. Also if you use the Python `with` statement, your files will also automatically be closed. Anyway here's what I suggest:

```
def copyAndWriteExcludingPoundSigns(origFile, origFileWithOutPounds):
    with open(origFile,"r") as origFileObj:
        with open(origFileWithOutPounds,"w") as modFileObj:
            for line in origFileObj:
                if line[0] != '#':
                    modFileObj.write(line)
```

The two `with` statement could be combine, but that would have made for a very long and harder to read line of code so I broke it up.